# Reset password using phone number laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'am getting this error `The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST` when I try to redirect the user back if the token is invalid. How do I solve this?

ForgotPasswordController

```
  public function showPasswordResetForm(Request $request,$token)
  {
   $inputToken = $request->token;
   $tokenData = DB::table('password_resets')
    ->where('token', $token)->first();
    $token = $tokenData->token;

    if ($inputToken != $token) return redirect()->back()- 
      >withErrors(['token' => 'Token doesnt exist']); //redirect  
         back if the token does not exist.
      return view('auth.passwords.reset')->with('token', $token);
   }
```

Blade

```
 <div class="card-body">
   <form method="GET" action=" 
     {{route('check.token',$token) }}">
       @csrf
    <input id='token' type="text"class="formcontrol @error('token') 
      is-invalid @enderror" name="token" required 
        autocomplete="token"autofocus>
           @error('token')
           <span class="invalid-feedback" 
             role="alert">
           <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
            </span>
             @enderror
    </div>
   </div>
```

Routes

```
Route::get('reset-password/{token}', 
       'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showPasswordResetForm')- 
       >name('check.token');
```

Comment: What does `php artisan route:list` return for reset-password ?

Comment: I have created my own reset password so there is  password-reset which returns  `Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendPasswordResetToken` @PHPer

Answer (score 0):

In your form, specify  POST method, instead of GET

From  `<form method="GET" action="....`

To `<form method="POST" action=" 
         {{route('check.token',$token) }}">
           @csrf
        <input id='token' type="text"class="formcontrol @error('token') ...`

You your Form is sending  two tokens. `_token`  defined by Laravel @csrf  and  `token`  that you defined.

Redo your Controller  as :

```
  //Notice the removal of $token from function variables
  public function showPasswordResetForm(Request $request)
  {
   $inputToken = $request->token;
   $tokenData = DB::table('password_resets')
    ->where('token', $inputToken)->first();
    $token = $tokenData->token;

    if ($inputToken != $token) return redirect()->back()- 
      >withErrors(['token' => 'Token doesnt exist']); //redirect  
         back if the token does not exist.
      return view('auth.passwords.reset')->with('token', $token);
   }
```

Assuming your blade is what you want, you should be fine

Comment: I have changed GET to POST still is not working, throwing the same error @PHPer

Comment: I removed the $token from the function variables. Have a look

Comment: the $token becomes undefined in this line `$tokenData = DB::table('password_resets')
     ->where('token', $token)->first(); `

Comment: I redited check new code (I had forgotten to rename `$token` to `$inputToken`) in the  `->where('token).... ` part of the controller

Comment: That works only when the token is True, if it's false `$token = $tokenData->token;
` throws an error `"Trying to get property of non-object"` because it returns null

Comment: In that case do due deligence and check if it's defined. In fact, that's the best practice